# Is it possible to call a stored procedure from a trigger in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I have a stored procedure, which upon calling, will update many tables I created.

Now I want the update to be done automatically.

Every Friday, all the databases will be updated with new data. My tables are created base on the tables in these databases, and I want my tables to be updated as well.

So, what I want to achieve is, when the tables in the databases are being updated, it will trigger, or whatever, the stored procedure to update the tables

however, I read that trigger cannot use the CALL statement to invoke stored procedures that return data to the client or that use dynamic SQL, so i am stuck here. is there any other method I can use?

Comment: We do not really know what your goal is, so it is hard to help in any way.

Comment: If the Friday base-table updates are scheduled then why not just schedule your SP to run after the base tables have been updated?

Comment: Yes it is *possible* to call a procedure from a trigger. Just not *any* procedure. There are restrictions. But from the description, a MySQL trigger doesn't seem to be the best fit for what we are trying to accomplish. (I'm assuming that the procedure doesn't need to be called for each and every row that is being inserted/updated/deleted, that we aren't intending to process row by agonizing row.) If we want a procedure to execute at a scheduled time, we can use MySQL `EVENT` scheduler. But it seems like the execution of the procedure should only be performed *after* the load of the tables.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes, I think using event_scheduler will be a better choice. And it is correct that I dont need the procedure to be called every time there are actions in the table. I am reading about event_scheduler now, if you guys have any good source, please leave me the link here. Thanks a lot.